# ionic 2 parsing error

Tags: angular, ionic2

I keep getting parsing for [latitude]="{{location.lat}}" I try latitude="{{location.lat}}" and latitude="location.lat"but it dones not to be working

```
 <div  *ngFor="let location of info">
     <agm-map [latitude]="{{location.lat}}"[longitude]='{{location.lng}}' [zoom]="15"
          [zoomControl]="false">
      <agm-marker [latitude]='{{location.lat}}' [longitude]='{{location.lng}}'></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the expression without **`{{}}`**

```
 <div  *ngFor="let location of info">
     <agm-map [latitude]="location.lat"[longitude]='location.lng' [zoom]="15"
          [zoomControl]="false">
      <agm-marker [latitude]='location.lat' [longitude]='location.lng'></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
 /div>
```

Comment: Just a fix: use `"..."` in `HTML`s instead of `'...'`

Comment: okay so this did fix the parsing but now the map blank and when I click I get this error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.x')